# Area Lighting In Ray Tracing

Tags: graphics, area, raytracing, lighting

I have a quick question about area lighting in ray tracing. I am learning this subject from [Ray Tracing from the Ground Up](http://www.raytracegroundup.com/index.html) and the result of my area light is like this when no antialising is applied: [image: NO AA]

As you can see there are lots of noise in the image. When I apply antialising, it looks fine and looks like this when 256x AA is applied:

[image: AA 256x]

[The change in the shadow color is trivial, I changed some properties of shadow]

My question, is this the way area lights behave or am I doing something wrong? Because rendering first one takes only 4 *seconds* but the latter one takes almost 20 *minutes*. It feels like there is something wrong.

The only difference between my point light class and area light class is `get_direction` function.

**Point Light's `get_direction` function:**

```
virtual Vec get_direction(ShadeRec& sr)
{
return Vec(position.x-sr.hit_point.x, position.y-sr.hit_point.y, position.z-sr.hit_point.z).norm();
}
```

**Area Light's `get_direction` function:**

```
virtual Vec get_direction(ShadeRec& sr)
{
    Vec newLocation;
    newLocation.x = position.x + radius * (2.0 * rand_float() - 1.0);
    newLocation.y = position.y + radius * (2.0 * rand_float() - 1.0);
    newLocation.z = position.z + radius * (2.0 * rand_float() - 1.0);
    return ((newLocation - sr.hit_point).norm());
}
```

Comment: In the former case, how many samples do you take? I would guess you're just seriously undersampling the area light, causing the results you see.

Comment: Former one sends one ray per pixel, and the other one sends 256 rays per pixel. So do you mean that there is no way to achieve the result of the second one without any(or less) AA?

Comment: Well, you could try different (adaptive) sampling strategies. But for the implementation you have, the result is as expected. At least that's a positive. ;) Edit: From the table of contents I gather that later chapters of that book discuss exactly that. Perhaps worth a look?

Comment: Do you mean the Ch. 17 Ambient Occlusions?

Comment: Totally, you need to shoot more rays when sampling direct lighting from area lights.

Answer (score 3):

The rendering times you posted make perfect sense to me:

```
4 seconds * 256 ~= 17 minutes
```

The overhead introduced by the random number generator sums up to the rest.